# Deleting DOM elements with button.onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

As I am learning javascript I was testing different things. I made a small function:

```
foo("div", "button");

function foo(divId, buttonId)
{
    var flag = 1;
    var button2;

    document.getElementById(buttonId).onclick = function() {

        if (flag) {
            button2 = createButton("Ceaning Service");

            var span = createSpan("I will be removed");
            var div = document.getElementById(divId);
            div.appendChild(span);
            document.body.insertBefore(button1, div);
            flag = 0;
        }

        if (!flag) {
            button2.onclick = function() {
                div.removeChild(span);
                document.body.removeChild(button1);
                flag = 1;
                return;
            }
        }   
    }
}


function createButton(text)
{
    var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    button.innerHTML = text;

    return button;
}

function createSpan(text)
{   
    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    span.innerHTML = text;
    return span;
}
```

I can click the second button without errors only when I click the first button `Click Me` once. When I click `Click Me` button more than once and try to click the second button, it shows `div` is undefined. (`span` is undefined too, but it won't show because browser reaches `div` first).

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="button">Click Me</button><br>
        <div id="div"></div>
        <script src="test3.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I played around with this function and when I declare `span` and `div` before `...(buttonId).onclick =...` it works.

So why this code only works when I click `Click Me` once? I think with the second click it cannot reference to the created elements, but not sure why.
And although it removes those elements, will they be removed by the garbage collection as well or is there some kind of a memory leak happening?

And please try not to reference jQuery or some other libraries/frameworks. It would only complicate things for me for now.

Comment: Had a quick look on it. You are missing semicolons after attaching the anonymous functions to variables, you are declaring local variables inside the functions (var button!= button) and is a good practice to call functions that have been read already.

Comment: @adr1Script - Yes. I had not noticed those semicolons. However, plase specify the other points.